# pivot a query adding information from another table

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

I need help trying to pivot the table derived from the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS 
(
    SELECT start_date as period, end_date
    FROM progetti
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(period, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), end_date
    FROM dates 
    WHERE period < end_date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
)
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.period, '%m-%Y') AS period, COALESCE(total, 0) AS total, COALESCE(s.tipo,0) AS tipo
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%Y') as 'period', 
  COUNT(items_header.id) as 'total' ,
  items_header.tipo 
  FROM items_header  
  WHERE progetto=1
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%Y')
) s on s.period = DATE_FORMAT(d.period, '%m-%Y');
```

and returns the following set of data:

| period | total | tipo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 02-2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 03-2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 03-2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 04-2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 05-2022 | 3 | 1 |
| 06-2022 | 2 | 1 |
| 07-2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 08-2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 09-2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 10-2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 11-2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 12-2022 | 0 | 0 |

What I am trying to build is a different result:

| period | tipo 1 | tipo=2 | tipo=3 | tipo=4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 03-2022 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 04-2022 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 05-2022 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 06-2022 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 07-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 08-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 09-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

So that months are repeated only once and the count of items is splitted by tipo in columns. I am trying to build a dataset that will populate a chart.js graph (one line for each tipo) and I am looking how to build it in mysql.

EDIT:
items_header table

| ID | created_on | tipo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-03 | 1 |

and so on (it is a ticketing system header table)

item_type_catalog table

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

Comment: without items and item type we can' reproduce your problem see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nbk I have added a sample of the two tables but for items_type_catalog I have also removed the join since it is not necessary.

Comment: are there only 4 types or canthere be much more

Comment: no types will always be these four

Comment: you need to provide more data and tables see if you can run your query here https://dbfiddle.uk/MAMjW6YD

Comment: @nbk here you are https://dbfiddle.uk/m_LxTMtt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is a simple pivot, as there are only 5 types and you can easily add more by adding a new `MAX(CASE WHEN` line to the last `SELECT`

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS 
(
    SELECT start_date as period, end_date
    FROM progetti
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(period, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), end_date
    FROM dates 
    WHERE period < end_date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
), CTE aS (
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.period, '%m-%Y') AS period, COALESCE(total, 0) AS total, COALESCE(s.tipo,0) AS tipo
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%Y') as 'period', 
  COUNT(items_header.id) as 'total' ,
  items_header.tipo 
  FROM items_header  
  WHERE progetto=1
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%Y'), items_header.tipo
) s on s.period = DATE_FORMAT(d.period, '%m-%Y'))
  SELECT 
  period
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN tipo = 1 THEN total ELSE 0 END) tipo_1
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN tipo = 2 THEN total ELSE 0 END) tipo_2
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN tipo = 3 THEN total ELSE 0 END) tipo_3
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN tipo = 4 THEN total ELSE 0 END) tipo_4
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY period
ORDER BY period
```

| period | tipo_1 | tipo_2 | tipo_3 | tipo_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 03-2022 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 04-2022 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 05-2022 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 06-2022 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 07-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 08-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 09-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_4DkkZYg)